# Check Process using Shell Script

Tags: java, linux, sh

I am developing a Java program which checks the running processes, if not start that process. In my context I am executing the .sh file which is like this.

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "Hello World..."
cnt=`ps -eaflc --sort stime | grep clientApplication.jar | grep -v grep | wc -l`
if [ $cnt = 3 ] 
then
        echo "Services for Pigeon are already running..."
else
        echo "Starting Services for Pigeon..."
        echo `java -jar clientApplication.jar`
fi
```

But it's not working. What's the problem?

Comment: what did you mean "not working"

Comment: Is this intentional?  **echo \`java -jar clientApplication.jar\`**

Comment: The echo outside the if condition works but the echo inside the if condition dont work.Is there any error in the if condition or any other errors.

Comment: yes that is intentional. If the process is not running i have to run that jar file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the test expression works. Hope this helps !!

```
echo "Hello World"
cnt=`ps -eaflc --sort stime | grep clientApplication.jar |grep -v grep | wc -l`
if(test $cnt -eq 3) ;
then
    echo "Services for Pigeon are already running..."
else
    echo "Starting Services for Pigeon..."
    echo `java -jar clientApplication.jar`
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure. Try this

```
cnt=$(`ps -eaflc --sort stime | grep clientApplication.jar | grep -v grep | wc -l`)
if[$cnt -eq 3]; then
```

Just try this

Answer (score 0):

echo won't execute anything it will just print the content what is there in double quotes.

So if i have understood your requirement you should be doing this instead of

echo "Hello World"
cnt=`ps -eaflc --sort stime | grep clientApplication.jar |grep -v grep | wc -l`
if(test $cnt -eq 3) ;
then
    echo "Services for Pigeon are already running..."
else
    echo "Starting Services for Pigeon..."
     `/bin/java -jar clientApplication.jar`
fi

Hope this will work, i haven't tested it now

Answer (score 0):

1. Equality checks should be ==, = is assignment

   I'd use $(expr) rather than `expr`

   if(expr) not if[expr]

   not sure if you intend to echo the java line or not, it's not going to start the jar by telling it to print. I got rid of the echo since you said you wanted to start it.

so if you try this, it will work:

```
    #!/bin/sh
    echo "Hello World..."
    cnt=$(ps -eaflc --sort stime | grep clientApplication.jar | grep -v grep | wc -l)
    if($cnt==3) 
    then
        echo "Services for Pigeon are already running..."
    else
        echo "Starting Services for Pigeon..."
        java -jar clientApplication.jar
    fi
```